# How does C extention keyword typeof work when we pass a pointer as parameter?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I use GNU compiler and find the usage of typeof like typeof(ptr + 1) instead of typeof(ptr),that's interesting ,and push me to find out what typeof does .

I write test code:

```
struct haha
{
    int a;
    int b;
    void *c;
};

struct haha myhaha;

int main(void)

{

typeof(&myhaha + 1) _tmp = &myhaha;
return 0;
}
```

and get the assembly code:

```
 80483e4:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483e5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483e7:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483ea:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
 80483ed:   c7 44 24 1c 1c a0 04    movl   $0x804a01c,0x1c(%esp)
 80483f4:   08 
 80483f5:   b8 e0 84 04 08          mov    $0x80484e0,%eax
 80483fa:   c7 44 24 04 1c a0 04    movl   $0x804a01c,0x4(%esp)
```

I can find line 80483ed move the address of myhaha . typeof(ptr + 1) and typeof(ptr) have the same Assembly code. How typeof get the type of the parameter in deed?

Comment: If you're using C++, just use `decltype`. No need for compiler extensions.

Comment: `typeof`, like `decltype` does everything at compile time AFAIK. Nothing should happen in the assembly.

Comment: If you are looking at the assembly for the obj instead of the exe, then there is a relocation entry in the obj file and the linker will fill in the address of myhaha on top of the 0x0.